# Error in if (lastnote[i] < 50) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to learn R. So I am beginner. I want to write a code as below and I have problem. If you help me, I will aprreciated.

This is just my practise. I have been reading some books about R and I have been trying to do something

```
class1 <- data.frame(name=c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10"), 
            surname= c("b1","b2", "b3", "b4", "b5","b6","b7","b8","b9","b10"),
            exam1= c(25,35,55,65,75,35,80,90,100,65),
            exam2 = c(56,65,25,95,78,69,45,23,45,63),
            final= c(65,55,78,93,65,89,89,95,100,75))
lastnote <- (((class1$exam1+class1$exam2)/2)*0.4 + (class1$final*0.6))
lastnote
class1[,"lastnote"] <- lastnote

for (i in lastnote)
if(lastnote[i] < 50) {x= "FF"
} else if(lastnote[i] < 60) {x= "CD"
} else if(lastnote[i] < 65) {x= "CC"
} else if(lastnote[i] < 70) {x= "BC" 
} else if(lastnote[i] < 80) {x= "BB"
} else if(lastnote[i] < 90) {x= "AB"
} else {x= "AA"}
```

x will be the letter numbers of students in this example.
I expect to create a vector as named x or new column in class1 
thank you very much for your help.

Comment: are you trying to access the `lastnote` variable in the list or are you trying to add a column that possess the values?

Comment: You iterate over elements of lastnote. Then you can't use `lastnote[i]` but instead just use `i`. Otherwise iterate over the numbers from 1 to the length of `lastnote` by using `for(i in 1:length(lastnote))` for your code to work.

Comment: Hi Jenks, I am tryingto add a column in values

Comment: Hi julian, Yes It worked. Thank you . but when I look the x, just "FF" was written

Comment: @pomatomus you affect a single value at each iteration at the same position, you need to affect the result in the right position of a vector

Comment: @Clemsang exactly you are right. . thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` in `base` R:

```
class1$letters <- cut(class1$lastnote, breaks = c(0, 50, 60, 65, 70, 80, 90, 100), labels = c("FF", "CD", "CC", "BC", "BB", "AB", "AA"))
class1
```

Output :

```
   name surname exam1 exam2 final lastnote letters
1    a1      b1    25    56    65     55.2      CD
2    a2      b2    35    65    55     53.0      CD
3    a3      b3    55    25    78     62.8      CC
4    a4      b4    65    95    93     87.8      AB
5    a5      b5    75    78    65     69.6      BC
6    a6      b6    35    69    89     74.2      BB
7    a7      b7    80    45    89     78.4      BB
8    a8      b8    90    23    95     79.6      BB
9    a9      b9   100    45   100     89.0      AB
10  a10     b10    65    63    75     70.6      BB
```

Answer (score 0):

I would utilize `dplyr` package to do this coupled with `case_when` function.

```
class1 %>% 
    mutate(lastnote =((exam1+exam2)/2)*0.4 + (final*0.6),
           Final_Value = case_when(lastnote < 100 ~ 'AA',
                                   lastnote < 90 ~ 'AB',
                                   lastnote < 80 ~ 'BB',
                                   lastnote < 70 ~ 'BC',
                                   lastnote < 65 ~ 'CC',
                                   lastnote < 60 ~ 'CD',
                                   lastnote < 50 ~ 'FF'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same looping condition with few changes

```
xx<-c()
for (i in unique(lastnote)){
  if(i < 50) {x= "FF"
  } else if(i < 60) {x= "CD"
  } else if(i < 65) {x= "CC"
  } else if(i < 70) {x= "BC" 
  } else if(i < 80) {x= "BB"
  } else if(i < 90) {x= "AB"
  } else {x= "AA"}
  xx<- append(xx,x)
}

print (xx)
[1] "CD" "CD" "CC" "AB" "BC" "BB" "BB" "BB" "AB" "BB"
```

Comment: @pomatomus thanks a lot you can vote if you find an answer to your problem

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did. How can I vote? I do not know. As you see, I am new in this site.

Comment: @pomatomus just click up arrow above 0, so we get votes and 10 points. if you also tick mark it below we get 25 points

Comment: @pomatomus you can vote up/down for as many answers you want and accept the best one according to you